# Photochemical Bromination of Cyclohexenes

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am still very confused with the bromination of alkenes. Can I ask help in finding the structure of the main product when each of these 3 are subjected to photochemical bromination? I know for a fact that the Br will replace an H atom, but I don't know what to do anymore if there's another functional group present at one/both ends of the alkenes. [image]

Comment: This is a radical driven process, so you need to identify the most stable radical intermediate. Note that allylic radicals are pretty stable.

Comment: All 3 of the compounds are unsaturated so it is also worth noting what the source of bromine is so we don't see electrophilic addition.